# Deploying Gstreamer 1.0 for Win32

Tags: c++, windows, deployment, sdk, gstreamer

I have successfully compiled a project with the SDK of 1.5.2. I took that application and the dlls to another machine, and it said it was not a valid Win32 application.

I compiled on a Win64 OS. Am I supposed to install Gstreamer on the other machine to run this application, or am I missing some dlls?

I have uninstalled Gstreamer from the computer I compiled it on, and ran the application with no problems, but when I run it on another machine it said not valid Win32 application.

Application compiled on Windows 7 64-bit.
Application target to run on Windows XP 32-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in visual studio 2012 update 4 I need to select a few things to make it work.

Project Properties
1. Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> Left Windows on top under SubSystem select **Console or Windows**
2. Configuration Properties -> General -> Left window under Platform Toolset select "**Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)**"

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dependency-walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) to check for required but missing DLL dependencies on the machine you want to deploy to.

Typically, you are missing the required C++ redistributable runtime for your specific Visual Studio version on the target machine.